# Array Key Values In Magento Template Files

Tags: php, magento, templates, mustache

Within a Magento template file how can you output the value of an array key.

For example:

> {{var rewards.UsablePoints}}

will return

> Array

The contents look like this:

[0] (int) => 12

---

Using magento's mustache syntax ({{...}}) how would I display "12" instead of "Array".

Comment: have you tried `{{var rewards.UsablePoints[0]}}`?

Comment: I've tried it and I get Array

Answer (score 1):

```
{{var rewards.UsablePoints.0}}
```

Comment: but that's how it works. could you do a var_dump of your array?

Comment: Function array dereferencing is possible from PHP 5.4: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: array(1) { [1]=> int(80) }

Comment: I know that i refd key 0 to start with. that is not the issue

Comment: I've still not resolved this. 
I think it may have to do with the UsablePoints being a method call and then trying to stack the array key after it.. either way {{var rewards.UsablePoints.0}}
returns Array

Comment: can't you prepare a variable usablePoints so that you don't have to go two levels deep?